# Limit-To find the value of a and b.

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

Can anyone give the technique to attend this type of problem?

Comment: Are you dividing by x?

Answer (score 4):

We get

$$\lim_{x \to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+x+1}{x+1}-ax-b\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x \to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+x+1-ax^2-ax}{x+1}-b\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x \to\infty}\left(\frac{(1-a)x^2+(1-a)x+1}{x+1}-b\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x \to\infty}\left(\frac{(1-a)x+(1-a)+\frac 1x}{1+\frac 1x}-b\right)$$

For this limit to exist the coefficient of $x$ in the numerator must be zero. This tells you the value of $a$. You find $b$ by setting the final limit to $4$.

Comment: You can use `\lim` to typeset $\lim$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: You are correct. I just fixed that thanks to you. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: You are welcome=)

Comment: is b = -4 and a = 1?

Comment: @Bot: Yes, that is right. (Did you change the answers after first posting your comment? I thought I saw $b=-3$ but my eyes may be bad.)

Comment: Yeah I changed my answer from -3 to -4 your eyes were accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try to rewrite $$\frac{x^2+x+1}{x+1}\quad \text{ as }\quad  \frac{(x+1)^2-x}{x+1}. $$

Comment: What is the use of doing it?Cannot simplify?

Comment: @user146181 this allows you write your limit as $\lim _{x\to \infty}(-ax-b + (x+1) -\frac {x}{x+1})$, which should be easy to study.